# TFLite model load error "RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: BroadcastArgs.Node number 0 (BroadcastArgs) failed to prepare."

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to load ma TF Lite model. The model was made from evaluation policy TF Agents

```
tf__dir = os.path.join(path_to_model)
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=tf__dir)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

And the is an error:

```
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ee8c0e46aeb2> in <module>
      5 print(interpreter.get_input_details())
      6 print(interpreter.get_output_details())
----> 7 interpreter.allocate_tensors()
      8 
      9 # Get input and output tensors.

~/anaconda3/envs/genv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py in allocate_tensors(self)
    240   def allocate_tensors(self):
    241     self._ensure_safe()
--> 242     return self._interpreter.AllocateTensors()
    243 
    244   def _safe_to_run(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/genv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py in AllocateTensors(self)
    108 
    109     def AllocateTensors(self):
--> 110         return _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper_AllocateTensors(self)
    111 
    112     def Invoke(self):

RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: BroadcastArgs.Node number 0 (BroadcastArgs) failed to prepare.
```

How can I solve it? No information with similar errors in Internet

Comment: share more details of the issue. Without knowing how your tflite model generated, which TF version used, what arguments you used when converting the model etc, it is difficult to help. From the error, I think you are using some custom ops that are not supported by tflite. May be try adding `allow_custom_ops =True`.

Comment: @vishnuvardhan-janapati Thanks, without `allow_custom_ops =True` it gives `loc(fused["Deterministic_1/sample/BroadcastTo@__inference_action_11129549", "StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/Deterministic_1/sample/BroadcastTo"]): 'tf.BroadcastTo' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': Ops that can be supported by the flex runtime (enabled via setting the -emit-select-tf-ops flag): BroadcastArgs,BroadcastArgs,BroadcastArgs,BroadcastTo.`  The model is SAC

Comment: Which version you are using? Can you share code?